# Need Someone To Explain .SelectedIndex

Tags: vb.net

I am fairly new to coding. I was working on a Visual Basic tutorial and I don't understand a line in the code. Below is the code.

```
    Public Class Form1
    Private Sub lstData_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstData.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim strName As String
        Dim strFavoriteColor As String
        strName = lstData.Items(lstData.SelectedIndex).ToString
        Select Case strName
            Case "Bryan"
                strFavoriteColor = "Madras Yellow"
            Case "Ashley"
                strFavoriteColor = "Sea Blue"
            Case "Jenifer"
                strFavoriteColor = "Morning Mist"
            Case "Eddie"
                strFavoriteColor = "Passionate Purple"
            Case "Katelyn"
                strFavoriteColor = "Red"
        End Select
        MessageBox.Show(strName & "'s favorite color is " & strFavoriteColor, "Select Demo")
    End Sub
End Class
```

The Line that I don't understand is **strName = lstData.Items(lstData.SelectedIndex).ToString**

I do not know what the point of **.Items** is. I am also having trouble understanding the code inside the parenthesis and what purpose it serves.

The closest I found to an answer is the following [website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.selectedindex.aspx). I'm hoping someone can explain it to me in a more understandable way.

Comment: From what I can tell lstData is your List box.  So you're getting the List Box items, and providing the indice of the selectedItem and outputting it to string to perform the switch case on.  Items is an collection of the ListItems in the list box and you access items of the Collection buy providing the indice of the one you want.  Therefore hes giving it the indice of the selected item which is the one he wants to do the switch on.

Comment: Your question really doesn't make much sense. `.Items` refers to the individual `Items` (objects) that are in the `ListBox`, and the `.SelectedIndex` is the index of the selected item (the one the user chose, or **selected**). There's not much more to say, and no way to explain it more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> lstData.Items(lstData.SelectedIndex).ToString

- `lstData` is a dropdown list.
- `lstData.Items()` will returns the collection of
  items(Bryan,Ashley,Jenifer,Eddie,Katelyn) present in that
  `dropdownlist`.
- Now see each item in that collection is having a `unique index` like
  this

  0->Bryan,1->Ashley,2->Jenifer,3->Eddie,4->Katelyn
- While `lstData.Items()` will returning the whole collection, the `lstData.items(index)` will return the particular item which is  having the index that we passed.

  For example: `lstData.items(0)` will return Bryan
- Now come to `lstData.SelectedIndex`. This property will return the index of the item that we have selected during runtime.

  For example: if the item selected from the dropdown list was Jenifer. Then the `lstData.SelectedIndex` will return 2.
- Consider, You have selected Ashley from the dropdownlist lstData.

  Now the code `lstData.SelectedIndex` will return 1.

  So the code `lstData.Items(lstData.SelectedIndex)` will be evaulated as lstData.Items(1).

  As we know `lstData.Items(1)` will return Ashley
- By the way `.ToString()` will return its instance in a string representation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I now have a much clearer understanding of how it works.

Answer (score 3):

`Items` is the `ItemCollection` for the `Listbox`, it is an object collection so it can store whole objects as well as simple text. The `SelectedIndex` is the element index of that collection starting at 0. So if you as for the `Items(selectedIndex)` you get the element of that collection.